# Why we need Context class in strategy design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

Why need Context class in strategy pattern?

for example, i want to compress files using either zip or rar compression. we can solve this using strategy pattern with following files.

```
1.ICompressionStrategy...Its interface
2.ZipCompressionStrategy ..implements IcompressionStrategy
3.RarCompressionStrategy ..implements IcompressionStrategy
4.CompressionContext..Inject IcompressionStrategy
5.Client..Inject CompressionContext
```

In above scenario why we need CompressionContext class? why can't i inject IcompressionStrategy into Client class?

What is the advantage of using CompressionContext class in above scenario? can i avoid that?

Here is the example I am talking about

http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-strategy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea of the strategy pattern is to customize *some part* of a task using a variable strategy.

The context, in the above example, does more than simply compressing a list of files. It could be, for example, a class that iterates through a folder hierarchy, selects files to compress, puts them in a list, uses the compression strategy, and writes the result of the compression to another location. This algorithm can be customized by providing a compression strategy, that is only used for the compression step of the whole algorithm.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you Nizet!..can you please suggest me good link or book for learning design patterns in detail?

Comment: wikipedia is a good resource for design patterns. You can refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns (See Patterns By Type Section)

Answer (score 3):

`Context` could decouple the `client` and `strategy`.
If there is no `context`, when you want to change the `strategy`'s interface, you must change the interface in the `client` too.
However, you may have no permission to change the `client` or it may cause merge conflict.
But if there is a `context`, you just need to change the achievement of `context` and don't need to change the `client`.